# UIGestureRecognizer "lost focus"?

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to figure out how to call an action after the UIGestureRecognizer has detected the gesture, when it "loses focus" (the user lifts their finger off the screen). 
So basically, if a user swipes their finger up for example, then lifts their finger off the screen, how can I detect that the finger was lifted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "state" property to detect the time when user ends up with swiping.

```
- (void)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
     //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your code, but UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded gets called as soon as the gesture is recognized, not after the finger has been lifted from the screen, any ideas?

Comment: You need to set cancelsTouchesInView and delaysTouchesEnded to NO for swipe gesture, and try to implement - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  
        for(UITouch* touch in touches)
        {
            if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)
            {
                NSLog(@"touched");
            }
        }
       
}